# Delete the extra space after special character in all the lines of text file

Tags: bash, shell, text, awk, sed

Following data represents 2 lines of text file:

```
1 2340: 2 1930: 1     
1 9: 3 4501: 1 45: 1 5620: 2
```

I want to delete the space after ":". So the output of above text file should be

```
1 2340:2 1930:1 
1 9:3 4501:1 45:1 5620:2
```

Comment: Please see the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what constitutes a "good" question. You haven't provided any code or shown any effort to solve your own problem. SO isn't a code service.

Comment: This is most basic of `sed`. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with any of the awk, sed, etc. 

In awk I could separate different columns based on field separator " ". I could also make ":" as a field separator but then I don't know what to do next.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcUid3OP_4OW-rwv_mBHzx9MmE5TxvvcQ) might be right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$ sed -e s"/: /:/g" file.dat
1 2340:2 1930:1     
1 9:3 4501:1 45:1 5620:2
```

EXPLANATION:

`sed -e "COMMAND"` will execute the command over file.dat`.

- `s` says sed to Substitute
- `/: /:/` are the chain to substitute and the chain desired, separated by `/`.
- Finally, `g` tells `sed` to be executed more than once time per line.

As @Tom commented, the quotes are better single quotes, and `-e` is not necessary, then:

```
$ sed 's/: */:/g' file.dat
1 2340:2 1930:1     
1 9:3 4501:1 45:1 5620:2
```

**EDIT 2** As @josifoski commented, the * after the space char, will allow more than one space, not just one

You can read some `sed` docs here:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Examples
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-basics-of-using-the-sed-stream-editor-to-manipulate-text-in-linux

**AWK GSUB**

```
$ awk '{gsub(/: */,":"); print}' file.dat
1 2340:2 1930:1     
1 9:3 4501:1 45:1 5620:2
```

Comment: No need for the `-e` and your quoting is irregular - it is more common (and recommended) to use **single** quotes around the **whole** command.

Comment: never knew about that!! thanks!! adding it to the answer

Comment: also /: */ will be better pattern covering more then 1spaces situations, g in this case is replace all occurences

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in awk?

Comment: what if there's/are a TAB character(s) space which are not visible to human eyes. Won't sed -i "s/:[ \t][ \t]*/:/g" filename.txt help? This assumes it'll substitute ": " or ":  *" or ":\t*" with just ":". Otherwise, sed -i "s/:[ \t]/:/g" filename.txt will do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F': ' -v OFS=":" '{$1=$1}1' file
1 2340:2 1930:1
1 9:3 4501:1 45:1 5620:2
```

Comment: Space can be a \t character. For ex: if he has a line "666666: f" where there's a tab character after : character but before character "f", then the above cmd wont work. This assumes a space can contain a tab character as well (invisible to human eyes... or use echo .... | od -cab)

Comment: Why do you say the space can be a tab character? Did the OP say that in a comment somewhere? It's not mentioned in the question or shown in his sample input or catered to by the accepted answer so I think you're wrong.

Comment: You are right:). I thought he's new to Unix/Linux, so he'd know what's a tab and how it looks.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the following**: If you want to replace ":" character followed by single/multiple spaces (" " or "\t" aka tab character(s)).

```
sed -i "s/:[ \t][ \t]*/:/g" filename.txt
```

or If you just want to substitute ":" with only one visible space into ":"

```
sed -i "s/:[ \t]/:/g" filename.txt
```

PS:

1. You can also use other characters for ex: ^ or # etc in place of / in sed command. 
   For ex: **sed -i "s#koba#loki#g" filename.txt**.
2. **-i** option (I used above) will update the file (i.e. in place update) instead of throwing the std output on screen. Don't use -i until you are sure, what you are updating. Taking a backup of the given file first, helps sometimes.